# How can I email reports generated from 'protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter' to stakeholders after successful test execution.

Tags: email, jasmine, protractor, report

I have a config file as below:

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {  
directConnect: true,

onPrepare: function() {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: './test/reports/',
      screenshotsFolder: 'images',
    })
  );
},

multiCapabilities: [
                   {
                     'browserName': 'chrome',
                   }],

framework: 'jasmine',



specs: ['zoo_spec.js'],


jasmineNodeOpts: {
showColors: true,  
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
                 }  
};
```

My question is is there any code i can write in order to send the report generated from jasmine2-html-reporter as soon as test execution is complete.

Comment: you can refer here as well, [Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033173/nodemailer-not-sending-mail-when-placed-in-protractor-config-afterlaunch-block?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using **onComplete** instead? Please refer below previous answer

[Unable to send Email using nodemailer in protractor.conf.js onComplete: function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970772/unable-to-send-email-using-nodemailer-in-protractor-conf-js-oncomplete-function)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This worked. Can you please try to make me understand why my code was not working?

Answer (score 0):

In the config `onComplete:function(){}` you can write custom code to send email. There are many nodejs email clients that you can reuse to send emails without reinventing. Here is the example client you can use https://nodemailer.com/about/ and also review SMTP section to for configuration;