# Send Email in Protractor, attachment not loading the full report has some Junk Values

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to protractor. I have generate a report using protractor-beautiful-reporter. While generating a report the html report is loading correctly. But the same report while getting as an email attachment the report is improper. Is there any npm package or is there any code to send the report attachment as a proper html.

[image: Report Image - screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How do you define `proper html`? The resources your report needs to display data are not being sent along with the email attachment. Inside the HTML there are links to javascript and css files. The HTML page on it's own does not know where these are and that's why you're seeing this 'blank' page. They're not `Junk Values`. The library this dashboard uses to display data isn't being loaded. Why don't you host the report on a shared drive or web location and send it as a URL?

Comment: Alternatively, create a dashboard for your team to view the reports on demand. Here's an example project which achieves just that: https://github.com/krynv/regression-dashboard

Comment: Thanks mate. Is there any way to automate this? The reports which is generated will be scheduled on daily basis and the client should be seeing the report. Is there any web location where i can share the report and making the url visible for all users, so using js code i can provide the url to navigate and mention the url in the content of the mail.

Comment: I'm sure you can tweak your automation runner to send out an email, yeah. See attached answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161376/8422218

I have used a slack application in the past to display the results of automation tests on demand/ scheduled basis, similar to this: https://github.com/krynv/regression-dashboard-slack-app - based on the tests from a test runner that looks kinda like this: https://github.com/krynv/Automated-Regression-Testing

Comment: Just to clarify, your test runner will know where the report files are saved. So just compose and send an email from the test runner when the job is done. Just make sure the user has access to the drive/ folder you're saving the report to. Alternatively, as suggested, create a 'dashboard' and save the reports to a directory where the dashboard can read said reports